# Efficiently swap vectors in PETSC

Tags: parallel-computing, petsc

The PETSC function [VecSwap](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Vec/VecSwap.html) after a few layers of abstraction [calls](https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc/src/f896727a0c6fbe98ba9ae82833ab3817fcf5697d/src/vec/vec/impls/seq/bvec2.c?at=master#cl-491) the BLAS primitive [`swap`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/dd4/dswap_8f_source.html), which  essentially copies data around (unless I am missing something).

It seems to me that there should be a O(1) implementation that can be obtained just by exchanging pointers, at least if the vectors are identical in all their characteristics (underlying storage and distribution between the nodes).

So, **is there a way to swap vectors without a deep copy in PETSC?**

Comment: This would be more appropriately asked of the petsc-users mailing list.

Comment: I disagree Bill, PETSc is open source and used in many different solving programs. Since stackoverflow is more for coding, I think this is the perfect place to come for PETSc help and it is the primary reason I made an account for this specific stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2):

What if one Vec was created by `VecCreateSeqWithArray` and the other not?  How would the user know which Vec holds the memory they allocated?  There is a dirty backdoor in `VecPlaceArray`, but using it is typically bad design.

Comment: How in the world did a PETSc developer get a downvote for this answer?

Comment: @BillBarth I did. The answer doesn't look helpful at all to me. It references a "dirty backdoor", but never describes it. It raises a concern that seems only an edge case that can be detected and treated by returning an error. Seems to imply "it doesn't exist because it's a bad idea to do it" but never arguments for it properly. Overall, it feels more like a comment than an answer. I realize that it's a developer, and I thank him for his great job, but that doesn't mean an automatic upvote in my book.

Comment: FWIW, I answered why such a function does not exist and cannot be implemented without either creating a monster (inconsistent behavior) or removing functionality that we feel is more important.  You should write your code to either swap the handles as in `Vec tmp; tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp;` or call VecSwap.  (It's unlikely the performance cost is significant unless you do it in an inner loop.)  *[I don't care about the votes, but I want to be helpful.]*